# Action Listener within Action Listener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener, jtextfield

I'm creating a vending machine for a school project, and I have to update the numbers when user clicks A1, A2, B1, B2 etc. Everything after the decimal changes, but anything before that does not. So if I click A1 which is set to 4 dollars 50 cents, and I then choose D4 which is 1 dollar 5 cents, my `JTextField` shows as 4 dollars 5 cents.

This is the buttons on the GUI:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tApuV.png]

[this is for buttons A and B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wtza.png)

[for buttons C and D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY3OO.png)

```
public void cost() {
    
     C_button.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
         public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
          button_1.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
             public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                total_order = 2 + 0.5;
                cost_total.setText(String.valueOf(total_order));

             }
            });
          button_2.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
             public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                total_order = 2 + 0.25;
                cost_total.setText(String.valueOf(total_order));

             }
            });
          button_3.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
             public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                total_order = 2 + 0.10;
                cost_total.setText(String.valueOf(total_order));

             }
            });
          button_4.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
             public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                total_order = 2 + 0.05;
                cost_total.setText(String.valueOf(total_order));

             }
            });
         } 
        });

       D_button.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
             public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
              button_1.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
                 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                    total_order = 1 + 0.5;
                    cost_total.setText(String.valueOf(total_order));

                 }
                });
              button_2.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
             public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                total_order = 1 + 0.25;
                cost_total.setText(String.valueOf(total_order));

             }
            });
              button_3.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
             public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                total_order = 1 + 0.10;
                cost_total.setText(String.valueOf(total_order));

             }
            });
              button_4.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
             public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                total_order = 1 + 0.05;
                cost_total.setText(String.valueOf(total_order));

             }
            });
             }
            });
```

Comment: Code should be posted in the forum as text, not as an image. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. I would guess you need to keep a "total" variable. So when you click A1 you add the amount to the total. When you click D4 you add the amount to the total. Then in both cases you update the label with the new value of the "total" variable.

Answer (score 2):

You're make this WAY more difficult than it should be.  First, I'd create a map of all the value combinations and their costs, something like:

```
Map<String, Double> costMap = new HashMap<>();
costMap.put("A1", 4.5);
costMap.put("A2", 4.25);
```

Then I'd create a String somewhere to track user input:

```
String register = "";
```

Then create a Action to handle the basic key pressed for the bulk of your keys:

```
public class VendingAction extends AbstractAction {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        register += getValue(Action.NAME);
        if (costMap.containsKey(register)) {
            costLabel.setText(costMap.get(register).toString());
            register = "";
        } else if (register.length() == 2) {
            //handle bad choice
            register = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you create your buttons it would be something like:

```
JButton buttonA = new JButton(new VendingAction("A"));
JButton buttonB = new JButton(new VendingAction("B"));
//so on and so forth.
```

Comment: It might be easier to use  `Map.of("A1", 450, "A2", 425,..);` just to reduce the typing.  The value could be divided by `100.0`. to get the actual amount.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that existed.  I'm an old school java dev long before all the functional programing stuff came into being and been doing a lot of Go lately.  Some of the new additions to Java are really nice.

Comment: It's been there since Java 9.  It creates an immutable map which isn't a problem since it can be passed to an implementation constructor if it needs to change.  The downside is that it is limited to about 10 entry pairs so further thought dictates it may not be appropriate. I',m lazy enough I would probably create a string of key,value pairs and populate the map that way.  Anyway, I agree with your answer.